# selecting the proper Python interpreter when using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, interpreter

I have Scrapy successfully installed.  I have recently successfully worked through the tutorial at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html  .

However, now when I run the spider from the correct directory as instructed:

`C:\My Projects\tutorial > scrapy crawl dmoz`.

I am getting the error:

`C:\Anaconda\python.exe:  No module named scrapy`.

This makes sense, because the interpreter that has access to the Scrapy module lives at

`C:\python27\python.exe`

My question is then, how do I point Scrapy to the correct Python interpreter?  Or is this an incorrect way of conceptualizing what I'm doing?

Yes, I am using Windows 7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the contents of your PATH variable? You might need to put `C:\python27\Scripts` or `C:\python27` ahead of the `C:\Anaconda` folder, but this might break other things on your system.

Comment: under `"PYTHON_HOME"` I have `C:\Python27;`  

whereas under `Path` I have `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts`

Comment: And those are before `C:\Anaconda;` in the PATH? What about your user-specific PATH?

Comment: I'm realizing that `C:\Anaconda;` is nowhere to be found in the PATH.  
Also, I apologize but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'user-specific PATH'?

Comment: In the environment variables window, there are two boxes, the one on top contains the user-specific environment variables, the one on the bottom contains system variables. At least on my system, both boxes have a PATH variable.

Comment: Ah yes, duh. Thanks.  Everything I've reported so far are user-specific variables and values.  As for the System variables, I've got `...;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts` in that order.

Comment: No problem :-) Try prepending `C:\Python27` to the system PATH and see what happens... If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas! Sorry!

Comment: AHA! It works!!  Now I have `...;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts` , and my spider is happily crawling!! Please rewrite as an official answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the path to the proper Python executable is **before** the path to any other Python executable. You should add `C:\Python27` to the beginning of your system PATH variable. Beware: this may break things you use Anaconda for!

For future Googlers - In Windows 7, the PATH variable can be edited by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> to open the System Control Panel. In the left hand bar, there is an option "Advanced System Settings". In the window that opens after clicking that, choose the "Advanced" tab, then at the bottom is a button that says "Environment Variables". Click that, then choose the variable named `PATH` from the bottom box for system variables. Click "Edit" and add the path as described above.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer.  Since apparently the order matters when listing Python executables with respect to Environmental Variable, is this why things may "break" later?

Comment: Yes. If you try and use the Anaconda `python.exe` later, if your program is not specific about which `python.exe` to use, it may find the wrong version. Also, the order matters no matter what operating system you use - Windows, Linux, Mac OS - order is important! Glad it helped :-)